# ¿Como validar un numero a través de un prompt?

Tags: javascript

Quiero ejecutar la función de tal manera que si el usuario ingresa un valor que no es numérico salte un `alert` indicando lo anterior.

Probe con lo siguiente pero no se ejecuta el `else`:

```
function cambiarLimiteDeExtraccion() {
  var cambioLimite = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese nuevo limite de extraccion"));
  if (typeof cambioLimite == "number") {
    limiteExtraccion = cambioLimite;
    actualizarLimiteEnPantalla();
    alert("Su nuevo limite de extraccion es: " + limiteExtraccion);
  } else {
    alert("Tiene que ingresar un valor numerico");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- El operador `typeof` solo te va a regresar un `string` indicando el tipo de dato asociado al valor de una variable, pero no nos es útil para validar el mismo, pues debemos para dicho objetivo usar alguna función que devuelva `true` o `false` dependiendo del estado del valor pasado
- Dado que desde el inicio usas `parseInt()` para indicar la llegada de valores enteros, entonces usemos `Number.isInteger()`
- El método `Number.isInteger()` nos dirá si el valor pasado como argumento es de tipo entero
- Además de lo anterior te hacía falta cerrar una llave del `else`

Tu código:

```
function cambiarLimiteDeExtraccion() {
    var cambioLimite = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese nuevo limite de extraccion"));
        if (Number.isInteger(cambioLimite)){
            limiteExtraccion = cambioLimite;
            actualizarLimiteEnPantalla();
            alert("Su nuevo limite de extraccion es: " +limiteExtraccion);
        } else{
            alert("Tiene que ingresar un valor numerico");
        }
}

cambiarLimiteDeExtraccion()
```

**Referencias**

- [Number.isInteger()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/isInteger)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un parseInt que esta convirtiendo a entero el texto ingresado y cuando realizas el typeof igual te va regresar un number por eso no pasa al else.

En vez de usar la validacion con typeof use la funcion isNaN

```
function cambiarLimiteDeExtraccion() {
    var cambioLimite = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese nuevo limite de extraccion"));
    if (!isNaN(cambioLimite)){
        limiteExtraccion = cambioLimite;
        actualizarLimiteEnPantalla();
        alert("Su nuevo limite de extraccion es: " +limiteExtraccion);
    } else{
        alert("Tiene que ingresar un valor numerico");
    }
}
```

en este link puedes ver mas documentacion de isNaN: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/isNaN

Comment: Gracias! Habia leido para hacerlo asi, pero comentaban que no es correcto validar un numero por isNaN, que no es una buena practica. Por eso lo hice asi. (Yo estoy aprendiendo)

Answer (score 0):

El problema de utilizar `typeof` es que un valor `NaN` es del tipo `number`. Si esto te suena raro, [puedes leer más sobre eso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801601/why-does-typeof-nan-return-number).

Por ejemplo, si el usuario no ingresa nada en el prompt. La primera condición será válida.

Para evitar, esto podemos expandir la primera condición:

```
if (typeof cambioLimite === "number" && !Number.isNaN(cambioLimite)) {

}
```

`Number.isNaN()` devuelve `true` si el valor es `NaN` (Not a Number) y `false` si el no lo es. Por eso lo estamos negando `!` en el ejemplo de arriba. Básicamente estamos diciendo:

"Si `cambioLimite` **es** del tipo `number` y ademas **no** es `NaN`"

Sin embargo, como `Number.isNaN()` ya nos dice si el valor es `NaN`, podemos simplificar el primer condicional:

```
if (!Number.isNaN(cambioLimite)) {

}
```

También es recomendable revisar que el valor ingresado sea mayor a cero. Ver ejemplo completo:

```js
let limiteExtraccion = 10;

function cambiarLimiteDeExtraccion() {
  let cambioLimite = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese nuevo limite de extracción"));

  if (!Number.isNaN(cambioLimite) && cambioLimite > 0) {
    limiteExtraccion = cambioLimite;
    alert(`Su nuevo limite de extracción es: ${limiteExtraccion}`);
  } else if (cambioLimite <= 0 ) {
    alert("ingrese un valor mayor a cero.");
  } else {
    alert("Tiene que ingresar un valor númerico.");
  }
  
}

cambiarLimiteDeExtraccion();
```

#### Acerca de `Number.isNaN()` vs. `isNaN()`

Unos de los problemas de la versión global [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/isNaN) es la coerción de cadenas de texto a números. Por eso se recomienda el uso de [`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/isNaN).